# ibtool failed with exit code 255 xcode 7.0 beta

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7

I have recently installed the xcode 7.0 beta and i have created my project in xcode 6.4 version.

I have already search for the solution but didn't get anything so please do not post any url or refer to this answer for help.

I have set the bitcode enable to false in project.

```
When run the app on xcode 7 it is throwing the error like below.
2015-09-17 17:08:50.667 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[4975:41214] Error creating notification handler for simulator  graphics quality override: 1000000
2015-09-17 17:08:55.488 ibtoold[4954:41059] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in     /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-8121.17/InterfaceBuilderKit/Document/Platform/IBIdiom.m:105
Details:  Assertion failed: !
Object:   <IBIPhoneIdiom: 0x7fcf0ca0b270>
Method:   -filePathWithTargetDeviceSuffixForBaseFilePath:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fcf09d44d90>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
0  0x000000010ce61ff9 -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
1  0x000000010ce61b2d _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
2  0x000000010ce61d44 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
3  0x000000010ce61ca6 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
4  0x000000010df4f2b5 -[IBIdiom filePathWithTargetDeviceSuffixForBaseFilePath:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
5  0x00000001172a2904 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
6  0x000000010de1e866 -[IBDocument finishCompilingWithOutputPath:options:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
7  0x000000010cc1eff6 (in ibtoold)
8  0x000000010cc214dc (in ibtoold)
9  0x000000010cc24f15 (in ibtoold)
10  0x000000010cc255c9 (in ibtoold)
11  0x000000010cc254a0 (in ibtoold)
12  0x000000010cc14bab (in ibtoold)
13  0x000000010cc24b0a (in ibtoold)
14  0x000000010cc23d6f (in ibtoold)
15  0x00007fff9820d5c9 start (in libdyld.dylib)
Command /Applications/Xcode-   beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

Comment: Any update on this ?

Comment: Yes what you need to do here all the storyboard and xibs which contains "~" sign need to rename.
Suppose you have Main~ipad.storyboard then you need to rename like Mainipad.storyboard.

Comment: thanks for you answer, I finally installed beta 3 and followed instructions here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13170?start=135&tstart=0

Comment: Thanks i will check it.